# Sublime Text Cancel Current Run Hotkey

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text, when I press <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>, it runs my application.  Is there a hotkey to force it to stop running?

I'm debugging some code that often hangs, and Sublime Text ends up completely hanging.  I'd like to know what hotkey I can press to stop this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> (Windows/Linux) will cancel a build that is in progress. There is no default key binding for OS X, but you can create your own if you wish. Navigate to `Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following:

```json
{ "keys": ["super+alt+b"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }
```

If you don't have any custom key bindings yet, make sure to wrap the above with square brackets `[]`.

Comment: I have this hotkey assigned, but it doesn't appear to do anything (I'm running Haskell)

Comment: Oh! Yes it does! And it says "Ctrl+Break" next to it--which does not work.